# Create SVG from base64 in javascript

Tags: javascript, svg, base64

i am new to javascript.

i want to create SVG from base64. i am trying http://jsfiddle.net/XTUmV/28/ 
but it doesnt show anything.

```
 var image="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==";
 var svgimg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "image");
 svgimg.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", 'xlink:href', image);

 document.getElementById("mySvg").appendChild(svgimg);
```

and html:

```
 <svg id="mySvg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"></svg>
```

base64 should be correct, cause i took it from this http://jsfiddle.net/MxHPq/ example

I am doing something stupid or just wrong approach?

thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You forgot to give the `<image>` tag some dimensions:

```
var image="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==";
var svgimg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "image");
// new
svgimg.setAttribute( 'width', '100' );
svgimg.setAttribute( 'height', '100' );

svgimg.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", 'xlink:href', image);


document.getElementById("mySvg").appendChild(svgimg);
```

[**Edited Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/XTUmV/29/)